# Action processing only one request at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My API Controller processes only one request at a time, tested by a console application with multiple threads. Every time a request comes, while the process is doing the parsing, the web application lingers until the process is complete. Every request takes about 2.5 seconds to complete.

[image]

This is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post() 
{
    return await Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        IActionResult result;
        var rom = new ResultObjectModel();

        try {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument));
                var obj = (XmlDocument) serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                rom = await _service.ParseXML(obj);
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            // ignored
        }

        var file = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(rom.FileLocation);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rom.FileLocation)) {
            switch (rom.ExportType) {
                case "docx":
                    result = File(file, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "file.docx");
                    break;
                case "docm":
                    result = File(file, "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12", "file.docm");
                    break;
                case "pdf":
                    result = File(file, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            result = BadRequest();
        }

        return result;
    });
}
```

`ResultObjectModel` class is just a simple class to hold information about where the file is located on the file system and what type of file it is.

```
public class ResultObjectModel 
{
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public string ExportType { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my `Program` class and its `BuildWebHost` method.

```
public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseLibuv(opt => opt.ThreadCount = 4)
            .Build();
}
```

What happens is that I recieve a `POST` request to the API with an XML file in the body of the request. I parse that file, create a document with some specific data on the local hard drive and then return that document as a `byte[]` using `File.ReadAllBytesAsync()`.

Edit :

Here's the console app that sends requests, note that I've hidden some sensitive information and replaced it with a string like API_URL:

```
  internal class Program {

    private const string Uri = "API_URL";

    private static readonly string FilesFolder =
        Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "TEST_FOLDER");

    private static readonly string Body = File.ReadAllText("XML_FILE");

    private static void DoStuff(int threadId, byte[] data) {
        for (var a = 0; a < 50; a++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread " + threadId + " , Request " + a + ".");
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(Uri);

            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.Accept = "application/pdf";
            request.Method = "POST";

            var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            using (var response = request.GetResponse()) {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                response.GetResponseStream()?.CopyTo(ms);
                File.WriteAllBytes(FilesFolder + "PDF_" + new Random().NextDouble() + ".pdf", ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Main() {
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Body);

        var t1 = new Thread(() => { DoStuff(1, data); });
        var t2 = new Thread(() => { DoStuff(2, data); });
        var t3 = new Thread(() => { DoStuff(3, data); });
        var t4 = new Thread(() => { DoStuff(4, data); });

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t3.Start();
        t4.Start();
    }

}
```

It sends a request to the api, recieves `byte[]` file and then saves it as a pdf. Note I also used `Task.Run(()=> {});` but the result was SAME. This is my second attempt at making it work.

Comment: Can you post code of your client?

Comment: Can you post your client code? Also, `return await Task.Run(async () =>` is not needed

Comment: What do you mean my client code? Code that sends requests?

Comment: yes, exactly, it would be relevant to see how requests are performed by your client.

Comment: Like I said, I read many other questions on the SO, and it was an advice in one of them. I added the code of the app that sends requests!

Comment: What do you think `opt.ThreadCount = 4` does? How would you expect there to be more than 4 requests at a time when the client only performs 4 requests at a time (one per thread)?

Comment: How sure are you that this is not being handled correctly? Because I think it is. Your 4 threads are each firing their request 0; and then each thread fires their request 1, and so on... They stay neatly in sync likely because the action's runtime is consistent enough. You can see minor variations as the threads are firing requests in different order: for request 0 it's 4321 but for request 1 it's 2134 (but they've currently stayed less than a single step removed form each other)

Comment: @Desomph `.UseLibuv(opt => opt.ThreadCount = 4)` means `don't use more than 4 threads`. *Don't* throttle your service or try to guess some optimal value. Your client code sends enough concurrent long-running requests to flood the (throttled) service

Comment: I know that it doesn't work properly, because if I run 2 console applications at the same time, I see the requests are parsed 1 by 1 still.

Comment: @Desomph you don't need to hard-code any "optimal" values. Just let the site work. .NET knows what each thread does, besides it *does* use a separate thread for each request. It uses a thread pool to handle requests based on load so it *doesn't* need such throttling.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the tip, I'll remove the limit. Didn't really know it's a limit though. Oh and your second comment makes sense. It could be that the APIis just not allowing a single origin to run a multiple requests at the same time?

Comment: @Desomph as for your code `public async Task<IActionResult> Post() 
{
    return await Task.Run(async () => ` is a problem. `Post` already runs in a separate thread and yet you start *another* thread. You just halved your already throttled input. Simply remove `return await Task.Run(async () => 
    {`. All operations that return tasks run asynchronously already

Comment: Okay, I already removed the Task.Run(()=> {}); from my controller.

Comment: Based on the comments and the initial explanation, I think we haven't seen evidence of an actual issue yet. (1) Tasks are not guaranteed to run in parallel. Its exact execution is the machine's prerogative (2) The test seems to be flawed. You test multiple calls with the exact same data. The execution time of every request is likely going to be the same and the threads might never noticeably go out of sync. (3) The test results don't actually show an issue; a correctly working application would look exactly like this too.

Comment: @Flater I assume you are right. I'll try to come up with different data and requests to check whethet there'll be any difference. Thanks for the detailed analysis!

Comment: @Desomph you don't need to return a buffer with a `File()` result either, you can pass the path to the actual file. This will let Web API itself copy the data to the output stream asynchronously. This means less blocking, less memory usage